# DDD - Many-to-many between aggregates

Tags: design, domain-driven-design

I have 2 aggregates: `Occupation` and `WorkActivity`.

An `Occupation` can have multiple `WorkActivity`. A `WorkActivity` can also belong to many `Occupation`.

The aggregate is a basic element of transfer of data storage, according to [Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html).

So the `WorkActivity` can't be a value object of the `Occupation` because when updating the `Occupation`, I don't want to update the `WorkActivity`, but the list of `WorkActivity` only. I would call it `WorkActivities`.

And the `Occupation` needs to know just the `content` of the `WorkActivity`, not other information like `description`, `image`, etc.

The question is should I store only the `id`s of the `WorkActivity` inside the `Occupation` as a value object, or should I create new `WorkActivity` value object with just needed information inside `Occupation` aggregate?

Comment: What is the behavior in these objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is should I store only the `id`s of the `WorkActivity` inside the `Occupation` as a value object,

Yes.

> or should I create new `WorkActivity` value object with just needed information inside `Occupation` aggregate?

If the preferred method of only storing the `id` results in a measurable performance bottleneck, then you might consider *caching* some of the contents of `WorkActivity` within `Occupation`. But it should be very clear that the actual `WorkActivity` aggregate is the source of truth and that the values stored within `Occupation` are there only for performance reasons and that they may be outdated by the time they get used.